# geocoder error response appears in Google search results

Tags: google-geocoding-api, googlebot

The CMS product I work on has a Google Maps integration for addresses, and it's a really simple, standard setup (simplified slightly for clarity here):

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    loc = results[0].geometry.location;
    initMap(loc); // renders map into DOM
  } else {
    var errorMessage = 'We\'re sorry, our request for a map showing "' + address + '" failed. Google Maps may be down, or the address may be incorrect.';
    // render errorMessage into the DOM
   }
});
```

Recently, some clients have noted that that even though the map works fine on their pages, that `errorMessage` appears in the Google search results description for the page. So it appears that the Googlebot is executing the geocoder request, but it's not working, and then the error message is getting indexed.

These are the possible results defined in `google.maps.GeocoderStatus`:

```
{
  "OK": "OK",
  "UNKNOWN_ERROR": "UNKNOWN_ERROR",
  "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT",
  "REQUEST_DENIED": "REQUEST_DENIED",
  "INVALID_REQUEST": "INVALID_REQUEST",
  "ZERO_RESULTS": "ZERO_RESULTS",
  "ERROR": "ERROR"
}
```

Just going by those names, our approach seems fairly appropriate to me — there is no status message there that seems like it could be identified as definitely bot traffic, and we prefer to identify, for our customers and their site visitors, that a map should be rendering there and some action may be necessary to correct it.

Can we handle this scenario in a way that does not result in an error message getting indexed as page content and included in search results?

Seems like this is probably more an issue with the Googlebot/indexer than the geocoding API, but tagging with both in hopes of finding an answer.

Comment: It's unlikely this is due to bots (but I recommend using [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961) anyway if you want to prevent bot traffic on your site). Can you try logging on the console the status code and error you get for troubleshooting purposes?

Comment: Well, definitely no desire to prevent bot traffic. Logging status in the JS console is not helpful, the status is always OK when hitting this page in a browser.

Comment: Sorry I hope I didn't misunderstand your described issue, but if the error message is displayed at times then this means the Geocoder status is not always OK since it's entering the else conditional. Could you log everything in a file to inspect later, for a specific time frame? Or simply display the actual status code in the error message you're showing in your front-end if possible. Also I recommend you check the metrics in the Cloud console in case there are any reported errors. We need to know what is going wrong before we can attempt to help.

Comment: It's not displayed in any user-facing instances we know of (barring network failures, when we'd expect and want it to). The issue is that it's displayed *in the Google search results for this page*. That seems, I think, to clearly indicate that the Googlebot executes the the geocoder call, but hits the else clause and indexes the result that's written to the page (that's the only way that text can wind up on the page). I suppose some server-side logging is going to be the only way to get to the bottom of this unless someone with really strong knowledge of how the Googlebot works can chime in.

Comment: I see, I understand now. I'm certainly no expert in Google bots but what I do know is that they are not going to automatically make your Geocoding requests fail which is why I find this unlikely. But if you want to verify this please try the suggested strategies (logging all failed request responses and using robots.txt for a specific time range). For a quick fix to prevent Google bots using your Geocoder implementation, you can simply do this: `if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Googlebot/i)) { return; } else { geocoder.geocode([...]) }`

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect that the bot is deliberately configured to load the Google Maps API script but then fail on the geocoder call, but it's totally clear that it's happening very, very regularly (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our+request+for+a+map%22 yields thousands of results of the exact issue, all from sites hosted on our CMS platform), so I just think it's a bug in how the bot works.

Comment: In fact, now that I see how many pages got indexed this way, it seems very likely that these could have all come from REQUEST_DENIED statuses — i.e., all these results are from indexes that have occurred at times when we've gone over the API request limit for a given month. So, yeah, I guess I'll be logging something to confirm that, or just not showing anything for that status, or both those approaches. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good! Please note though that the status code for going over your daily limit of API requests is OVER_DAILY_LIMIT (not REQUEST_DENIED which occurs when e.g. the API key is not restricted correctly or the Maps API is disabled). Let us know the results of your logging & testing from your side. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196486/discussion-between-rwwl-and-evan).